# Is the data inside the ViewData dictionary correlating to the Model Serialized?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, viewdata

In ASP.NET MVC3, when a view model is passed into a view using `return View(myViewModel);` it adds a definition to the ViewData dictionary, ViewData.Model, which holds myViewModel. In the view `@model myViewModel` will allow access of the view model data, alternatively you could also use `ViewData.Model`. Is the data that is passed into the ViewData dictionary serialized, or how is it stored for use in the model? I was under the impression ViewData was implemented by a caching strategy in server side memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

object Model is a property of ViewDataDictionary : IDictionary, ICollection>, IEnumerable>, IEnumerable.
ViewDataDictionary is a property of ControllerBase.

Please check the ASP.NET MVC source code from [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/a696a960a103) to find answers of your question.